I bought my first Blackrock iShares ETF today and want to know if I am now registered with Blackrock (data transfer from broker)
I bought my first Blackrock iShares ETF today and want to know if I am now registered with Blackrock (data transfer from broker)
I bought shares in a Blackrock ETF via Swissquote. Are my personal details (surname, first name, address, etc.) now in the Blackrock database or am I only known to my broker (Swissquote)?

Usually ownership is managed by the broker, this is what's called "holding in street name". Updating ownership of frequently traded high volume securities for every transaction is just too prohibitive and is essentially infeasible nowadays.

I don't know if this is true if EFTs, but for traditional mutual funds it is sometimes possible to transact directly with the investment company that runs them, buying and selling through the "house broker". That may be inconvenient if you are managing other investments, it if you want to do something more complicated than buy and sell, but it does mean they know who you are rather than having the shares held in street name.  In fact that's almost the only way I've invested, with the exception of a few ESPP shares in my employer.

@keshlam mutual funds work differently. There's no trading, you're buying in or redeeming.
